# How to create Video Upload Field in Ext.NET

Tags: c#, ext.net

**This is the File Upload Fields**

```
<ext:FileUploadField runat="server" ID="fufVideo" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Video Path"></ext:FileUploadField>
                                <ext:FileUploadField runat="server" ID="fufPhoto" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Title Image Path"></ext:FileUploadField>
                                <%--<ext:TextField runat="server" ID="txtDisplayOrder" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Display Order" AllowBlank="false"></ext:TextField>--%>
                                <ext:Checkbox ID="chkOnHomePage" runat="server" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Show On Home Page?"></ext:Checkbox>
                                <ext:Checkbox ID="chkIsActive" runat="server" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Is Active?"></ext:Checkbox>
                                <ext:DateMenu ID="dateAdd" runat="server" LabelWidth="90" FieldLabel="Added Date"></ext:DateMenu>
                                <ext:DatePicker ID="dateExpired" runat="server" LabelWidth="90" FieldLabel="Expired Date"></ext:DatePicker>
```

**And this is the code behind**

```
            string videoUrl = "";
        string imageUrl = "";          
        Client client = null;
        string folderName = "";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Client"] != null)
        {
            client = (Client)HttpContext.Current.Session["Client"];
            //folderName = client.ShortCode + client.ClientId;
            folderName = client.ShortCode;
        }
        if (fufPhoto.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fufPhoto.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FilePath = "Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName;
            bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
            if (!exists)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
            }
            fufPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName));
            imageUrl = FilePath;
        }
        if (fufVideo.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fufVideo.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FilePath = "Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName;
            bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
            if (!exists)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
            }
            fufVideo.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName));
            videoUrl = FilePath;
        }
```

But I can not upload video files. for uploading video files is there any unique field type in Ext.Net? pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your code work fine.(as far as I know ,u dont need any special field except of the uploadfield)I am able to upload both image and video successfully. here is the how I test it

aspx code

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server"></ext:ResourceManager>
        <ext:FileUploadField runat="server" ID="fufVideo" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Video Path"></ext:FileUploadField>
        <ext:FileUploadField runat="server" ID="fufPhoto" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Title Image Path"></ext:FileUploadField>
        <%--<ext:TextField runat="server" ID="txtDisplayOrder" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Display Order" AllowBlank="false"></ext:TextField>--%>
        <ext:Checkbox ID="chkOnHomePage" runat="server" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Show On Home Page?"></ext:Checkbox>
        <ext:Checkbox ID="chkIsActive" runat="server" LabelWidth="130" FieldLabel="Is Active?"></ext:Checkbox>
        <ext:DateMenu ID="dateAdd" runat="server" LabelWidth="90" FieldLabel="Added Date"></ext:DateMenu>
        <ext:DatePicker ID="dateExpired" runat="server" LabelWidth="90" FieldLabel="Expired Date"></ext:DatePicker>

        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="UploadImageandVideo">
             <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="UploadVideoAndImage">
                    <Confirmation ConfirmRequest="true" Title="Title" Message="Sample Confirmation Message..." />
                </Click>
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>

         </form>
```

code behind

```
  public partial class VideoFileUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void UploadVideoAndImage(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
        {
            string videoUrl = "";
            string imageUrl = "";

            const string folderName = "clientname";
            if (fufPhoto.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fufPhoto.PostedFile.FileName);
                string FilePath = "Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName;
                bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
                if (!exists)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
                }
                fufPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName));
                imageUrl = FilePath;
            }
            if (fufVideo.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fufVideo.PostedFile.FileName);
                string FilePath = "Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName;
                bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
                if (!exists)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/"));
                }
                fufVideo.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + folderName + "/" + FileName));
                videoUrl = FilePath;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm, thank you for your feed back. but still i can not upload video file. you made a database table for this, can u please share your that table pls?

Comment: I didnt make a database ,just upload the video and image to the folder on server as u did on your code

Comment: Status Code: Status Text: BADRESPONSE: Unexpected identifier
BADRESPONSE: Unexpected identifier.

any formation of video file sends this error. except video files any other files are uploading

Comment: can u show me how you upload I mean button clcik event

Comment: may be problem is related to the file size of the video ,if so,u need to set the max size file in  size in web config,or try to upload smaller vide and see if it works fine

Comment: I am going to try to set the file size in web config page.

Comment: try using direct event as I did my example instead of DirectMethod

Comment: <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="UploadVideoAndImage">
                    <Confirmation ConfirmRequest="true" Title="Title" Message="Sample Confirmation Message..." />
                </Click>
            </DirectEvents>

Comment: I tested both direct event and direct method and it works fine ,I guss the problem is the video file size,chech you config file and set it appropriate value